# List field-level checkout

Tags: list, permissions

When a user is updating a line item, once they click on a cell or field (say it's called "Description"), have that cell automatically "checked out" or "locked" or somehow "greyed out" so anyone else editing that same line item is prevented from making changes until the first person "Saves" their edits?

We are using SharePoint 2010.

To further clarify, we are using Custom Lists.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using document library or custom list?

Comment: Field-level checkout isn't available OOB, you can only check-out whole item and lock it for editing from others..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrent editing of a list item in a document libaray can be handled by check-in/check-out procedure but not for custom list. Multiple users can edit the same item in a sharepoint list at the same time…the first person to save her edit wins.I don't believe there's an option to lock list items.

So you can enable the version history of the list, so that you can check the detailed report.

Also check :
 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c24b224f-b51e-4b73-9806-0e1786888de8/how-to-lock-an-item-in-a-sharepoint-2010-list